# Drupal 7 AJAX disables my callback

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I have JavaScript attached to an element in a form that sends it's new value to a PHP callback function. The callback function queries the database and then returns a value that JavaScript then puts in a text box as its value.

I have experimented, and found that callbacks do not work on node edit forms. I assume it has something to do with the new AJAX functionality built into forms.

How to get around this problem?

Comment: What triggers the AJAX call? A click of a button? Entering text on a field? Have you tried looking at the Net tab in Firebug or Chrome? What does it say?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I used Firebug and got an interesting result - when I execute the JS from any page other than a node/edit, Firebug shows me POST http://127.0.0.1/objnum_callback.  When I execute the exact same JS from a node/edit page, I get http://127.0.0.1/node/edit/objnum_callback!

Comment: Is there any way around this?  Here is the JS:

Comment: jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
       url: 'objnum_callback',
       data: {}   
        });

Answer (score 1):

According to the code example that you posted, you are using a *relative path* in your AJAX request. Maybe you should try anchoring your request to the *base path* by using `/objnum_callback` instead of just `objnum_callback`. This will ensure that your request is pointing to the same place regardless of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking in to the [form API #ajax](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) attribute, more importantly `#ajax['callback']`? Personally I would go this route as it would allow your callback to be called when the form is being rendered rather than after render.

What I would look in to is altering the node form you're trying to change with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or a more specific form id for the kind of like hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter(). Once that is done you can modify the form field you were looking to have populated and add the `#ajax['callback']` and have it be the function you're trying to call via the `$.ajax.`

If you go this route you would be using Drupals native ajax framework rather than adding on over top of it.

Comment: Thanks Chad.  I gave up on #ajax['callback'] because the tutorials I have found are all based on forms created by the programmer.  I haven't found a tutorial that shows how to use it with drupal node edit, which is a rat's nest of unds, values, etc.  I have tried, but have been unable to figure out which part of the form to return from the callback.

Comment: Can you point me to a good tutorial?  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff Davidson I can probably whip up a short example module that would do this for you but I have a few questions. Why you are using ajax to populate that field? Also what form is this for it might help me make the example a little more accurate.

Comment: @JeffDavidson Take a look at this small module example. It takes the page node and populates a textfield on it with the admin user's username.

[altering default values on a form](http://pastebin.com/aXva8jSi)

To test this throw the code in to a folder titled simpleprepopulatedfield_example and inside a file with the same name but with the extension .module. After taht create another file with the same name as the folder but change the extension to .info and put the following in it [this](http://pastebin.com/X7HkD18m)

Comment: @JeffDavidson Depending where you're getting the javascript ajax request from this might be an easier way of obtaining that data. By doing it this way it's one page request rather than two. You can do this with pretty much any form element.